# Transfer Files Over WiFi Multiple Devices Multiple Platforms

Tags: wireless-networking, sync, file-transfer, wifi-transfer

What is the best way to transfer files of any size across platforms like Windows, Android and iOS which are connected to the same WiFi network.
App should transfer data using the local WiFi network and should not need working internet connection.

Comment: Try at [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this. The "less complicated" way would to set up a shared folder.
There are many articles on the Net how to do this and how to access them from android/IOS.

Another solution is to setup FTP. You could either do it from the windows machine, but the better option would be to use a router such as the Asus RT AC-56U that has the capabilities to transfer files between all 3 devices.

You could also use a cloud based solution, such as GDrive, OneDrive, etc, where you could upload documents and get them throughout all devices.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, without Internet connection, so no cloud services.

I know the opensource and multiplatform [Syncthing](https://syncthing.net/).
The official app has not client for iOS but [Mobius sync](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/mobiussync/id1539203216?ign-itscg=30200&ign-itsct=apps_box#?platform=iphone) is a client Syncthing compatible (requires iOS 14.1 or higher)